# Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove another inequality

Tags: inequality

So I know how to prove the inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}y_{i} \right)^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}^2 \right)$$

But now I need to prove that:

> If $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$ are positives, for i = 1:n, and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}$ then:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_{i}^2}{x_{i} + y_{i}} \ge \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}$$

I have to find something to substitute on the first inequality, but I don't know what.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+y_i\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{x_{i}^2}{x_{i} + y_{i}}\right) \ge \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}\right)^2$$

Using $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}$$ we get the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, but could you show or link me to some demonstration of the first inequality? Thanks

Comment: $\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+y_i\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{x_{i}^2}{x_{i} + y_{i}}\right) \ge \left[\sum_{i=1}^n \left((x_i+y_i) \cdot\frac{x_i^2}{(x_i+y_i)}\right)\right]^2$. Does this make sense now? I just used Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Yes, of course! Now I can see. Thanks!